# running hadoop program with hbase stuck at htable declaration

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I'm implementing hadoop program which requires hbase.
I'm using Hadoop 2.5.1 and HBase 0.20.6 (I first used 0.94.8 but after facing the problem I just try changing to 0.20.6 because the document of my original source code tell me, unfortunately that didn't solve the problem.)

After compiling the code using 'javac' and running the jar file, the jobs stuck at map 67% (the % changing based on the inputs).

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51053996/Pics/map_stuck.jpg
```

I tried investigate the problem by commenting parts of the code and find out that the HTable initiation is somehow the line.

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51053996/Pics/htable.jpg
```

There are still some clues that I have no idea it involve or not:

- The permission problem when I tried running "hadoop jar ..." by using 'sudo' (however, I had fixed this by issued some commands like "sudo -u hduser hadoop fs -chown ... and -chmod ...)

  ```
  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51053996/Pics/hbase_permission.jpg
  ```
- The 'jps' running after start-hbase: I need to issue 'sudo jps' so that I can see the H.. processes (if not I will see only the hadoops') and after running hadoop some processes such as HMaster disappears.

  ```
  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51053996/Pics/jps.jpg
  ```

Any help would be really appreciated :)

Comment: Update: after changing to hbase-0.98.10.1 and fixing some issues about permissions, I can run the start-hbase and jps without using sudo and seeing all of the H* stuffs (HMaster, HRegion, ...)

Unsolved: when I try running hadoop java program (with hbase) I ran into the problem: ""

any suggestions please.

Comment: Sorry for the above comment. I did some typos and didn't notice it in time of editing comment.
Here is the error: "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljava/lang/String"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem btw. By re-installing both Hadoop and HBase while double checking the compatibility very carefully (you can search for them in the apache official website). In my case, now I'm using Hadoop 2.5.1 and HBase 0.98.11

Hope this may help someone later on.